# ClientBuilder newBuilder() vs newClient()

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

Regarding `javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder`, I have read both the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html) and the [Jersey Documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html), but still it is not obvious to me when we should use `newClient()` and when we should use `newBuilder()`

I do notice that `newClient()` allows us to pass in a `ClientConfig`, and `newBuilder()` allows us to set `sslContext()`.  What if we need to do both?

Can anyone give me a quick summary on the two concepts?

Comment: How about calling withConfig()? https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder.html#withConfig-javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`newClient` is just a shortcut to bypass the builder when you only have a `Configuration` to pass in. If you need to set up both, you use the `newBuilder` method, e.g.:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .withConfig(config)
        .sslContext(sslContext)
        // Whatever else you set up
        .build()
```